# Build Perfect Swift error

Tags: swift, build, perfect

I just cloned the [PerfectTemplate](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate) repository on my machine. When I try to build the project I get the following error:

```
Compile Swift Module 'PerfectHTTPServer' (8 sources)
/Users/admin/Desktop/PerfectTemplate/Packages/PerfectHTTPServer-2.1.14/Sources/PerfectHTTPServer/HTTPContentCompression.swift:71:12: error: use of unresolved identifier 'UnsafeRawBufferPointer'
                let b2 = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: dest, count: Int(stream.total_out))
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer:6:15: note: did you mean 'UnsafeBufferPointer'?
public struct UnsafeBufferPointer<Element> : Indexable, Collection, RandomAccessCollection {
              ^
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/admin/Desktop/PerfectTemplate/.build/debug.yaml
Macintosh:PerfectTemplate admin$
```

Did anyone faced with this error before ?

Comment: Are you using the latest Xcode?  It looks like you're building a Swift 3 project with the Swift 2.x compiler.

Comment: I am using Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)

Comment: Macintosh:PerfectTemplate admin$ swift -v
Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0138-unsaferawbufferpointer.md), UnsafeRawBufferPointer was added in swift 3.0.1.

Comment: Upgrading to Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) - Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1) solves the issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to deploy Perfect on a mac, make sure you have the latest XCode (version 8.2.1 or later) and try running it again.